MongoDB Driver Java: 'unknown operator: $project' on server
I have the following java code that creates Bson filters (working as intended).
However when I try to add a projection to my filter I then get:
'unknown operator: $project' on server

What is the issue here within my code?
 private Bson createFilter(String name) {

        List<Bson> collectionFilters = new ArrayList<>();

        if (name != null) {
            filters.add(eq("person_name", name));
        }

        collectionFilters.add(projectCollectionFields());

        return and(collectionFilters);
    }

    private Bson projectCollectionFields() {
        return Aggregates.project(new Document()
                .append("_id", new Document("$cond", Arrays.asList(
                        new Document("$ne", Arrays.asList("$_id", null)),
                        "$_id",
                        "$$REMOVE"
                )))
                .append("name", new Document("$cond", Arrays.asList(
                        new Document("$ne", Arrays.asList("$person_name", null)),
                        "$person_name",
                        "$$REMOVE"
                )))
                .append("date", new Document("$cond", Arrays.asList(
                        new Document("$ne", Arrays.asList("$date_added", null)),
                        "$date_added",
                        "$$REMOVE"
                ))));
    }


what server version?

is filters here collectionFilters? collectionFilters.add(Filters.eq("person_name", name)); ?

@cmgchess it is com.mongodb.client.model.Filters

Filter and projection should be in separate aggregation stages.  How are you using these generated objects?

In your projectCollectionFields() you are trying to aggregate, you have to project only fields you want, e.g.
private Bson projectCollectionFields() {
    return Projections.fields(
        Projections.include("person_name", "date_added"),
        Projections.excludeId()
    );
}

fix  createFilter() like:
private Bson createFilter(String name) {
    List<Bson> collectionFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    if (name != null) {
        collectionFilters.add(Filters.eq("person_name", name));
    }
    return Filters.and(collectionFilters);
}

and then:
Document doc = collection.find(createFilter(name))
                .projection(projectCollectionFields())
                .first();


find and aggregate are different commands and both can use projection
